# How do you make Google Map have markers for several different places (such as gas stations)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

Im new to Android Dev but also knee deep in a project, just being held up by the APIs.

I am working on an Electric Vehicle app. It has an option to click a button (titled EV STATIONS) that takes you to a map. When you get to this map, it should have markers (which I want to be EV station drawable icons) on all EV stations in the direct area/city (I currently have it pointing to Atlanta).

I have the map set and loaded with an API key from Google console and all. The emulator runs and the map is of North America with a marker on Atlanta (where I want to focus it).

I would like for the map to be zoomed into the city of Atlanta, with all Electric Vehicle stations in Atlanta marked.

How do I do this? Is it possible?

Comment: It may help to know about: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility The key term is "points of interest".

Answer (score 0):

When your app starts you can state where you want the camera and the zoom level with the following line.

```
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM))
```

For the markers. I would suggest you make a class for these EV stations.
Everything on a GoogleMap is placed using a 'LatLng'. So it's best to have that datatype in your EVStation Class for ease of use. This class should also have at least a name, Id and LatLng. But you ideally would also store the address and other information you need for the app. The iD field is important, because when you click on marker, you'll location which EVStation it represents by their id's.

Once you have your EVStation Class. You'll have to find a way of importing this data. But just starting out, you can and write some temp data that gets initialed on app startup.

These EVStations that get loaded in will be put into an `ArrayList<EVSTation>();`

Once you have that arraylist, you can the loop through it to create markers on the map.

```
public static ArrayList<Marker> markEVStations(Context mContext,
                                                 GoogleMap map,
                                                 ArrayList<EVStation> eVStations)
    //Create an empty array to store the markers.
{   ArrayList<Marker> allEVStationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    //Loop throw the EVStations, createing a marker for them and adding that marker to allEVStationMarkers arraylist
    for (EVStation e : eVStations) {

        Marker evStationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(e.getLatLng())
                .title(e.getName())
                .icon(YOUREVSTATIONICON)
                .draggable(false));
        evStationMarker.setTag(e.getId());

        allEVStationMarkers.add(evStationMarker);
    }
    return allEVStationMarkers;
}
```

Just running the above method will put markers on the map. The ArrayList it returns isn't needed, but it makes it easier to use the markers individually once they've been created.

If you need more help with this project. I suggest just sitting down and breaking it up into a bunch of features (This is what the professions do). Then address each feature one at a time. Because right now, your question is very broad, and you provided no code. It's hard to give you a technical answer. My code example, may not fit your intended solution.
Good luck!